# Should I increment major version if I introduce a non-forward compatible change

Tags: semantic-versioning

I have an upcoming change that most likely will make newer documents fail to load in older versions of the program, but the changes will still allow old documents to be loaded. Is this an increase in major version or only minor version?

SemVer only speaks about backward compatiblity, but not the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are making a breaking change to the document format (an interface) that will break older versions of the program, therefore you must bump the major version. But you probably don't actually version the document format independently of the programs that process them, do you? If not, you have a design flaw.

Will the older program versions crash when they attempt to read this new format, or fail gracefully? If you have control of the document type | version specifier (file extension or internal signature), then you could arrange for your newer program to emit a different signature for documents that contain the new format. Will your new code offer the option to emit documents in the older format?

It's generally accepted best practice to bump the major version for these kinds of changes, because your new code's data interchange format breaks older code that might be expected to process the same kinds of documents. The forward | backward compat perspectives really are just different perspectives into the same kinds of things, with different nuances. The fact you asked this question the way you did, suggests that you don't understand what forward compatible means or the nuances of developing truly [forward compatible systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_compatibility).